# Laravel - Don't show the message before return

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I need help. I would like to display a message when the record is not found and return to the main page. I'm getting back, but without displaying the message, that is, I can't receive it in the view Show.

**Controller**

```
public function show(Request $request){         
            $mci = $request->get('mci');
            $entidades = Entidade::where('cd_cli', $mci)->get()->first();                                                                      
            if($entidades){             
                return view ('/entidades/show')->with('nome',$entidades)->with('cd_cli',$entidades)
                ->with('cd_atv',$entidades)->with('nom_atv',$entidades)->with('cd_nat',$entidades)
                ->with('nom_nat',$entidades);                           
            } else {                                                                        
                **return redirect('entidades')->with('error', 'Error!');**      
            }                                                   
        }
```

**Show View**

> I can't enter here!!!

```
@if(session('error'))  
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session()->get('error') }}
    </div>
@else


@section('conteudo')

<div class="container"> 
        
    <br> 
   
    {{ csrf_field()}}
    <table class="table table-primary"> 
    <tr>    
        <td>MCI: {{$cd_cli->cd_cli}}</td>
        <td>Entidade: {{$nome->nome}}</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>        
        <td>Atividade: {{$nom_atv->nom_atv}}</td>       
        <td>Natureza: {{$nom_atv->nom_atv}}</td>        
    </tr>    
    </table>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ route('entidade') }}'">Voltar à Consulta</button>       
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Preencher Formulário</button>
  
</div>
    
@endsection

@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the flash message and redirect it back from your controller function.

```
session()->flash('msg', 'Error!');
return redirect()->back();
```

And then you can get the message in the view blade file.

```
{!! Session::has('msg') ? Session::get("msg") : '' !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
@if(session()->has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session()->get('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. The problem is that I was inserting the message in the show and not in the index.